# Trying to mount Kubernetes volume to ceph rbd storage but getting FailedMount error

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, ceph

Showing FailedMount error while mounting Kubernetes volume to ceph storage rbd

Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[data], unattached volumes=[data kube-api-access-mxlkm]: timed out waiting for the condition.

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ceph-claim-dynamic
spec:
  accessModes:  
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: dynamic
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi

apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: dynamic
provisioner:  kubernetes.io/rbd
parameters:
  monitors: 192.168.122.82:6789,192.168.122.238:6789,192.168.122.124:6789 
  adminId: admin 
  adminSecretName: ceph-admin-secret 
  adminSecretNamespace: kube-system 
  pool: k8s 
  userId: kube  
  userSecretName: ceph-user-secret
  imageFormat: "2"


apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ceph-pod1
spec:
  containers:
  - name: ceph-busybox
    image: busybox
    command: ["sleep", "60000"]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: data
      mountPath: /data
      readOnly: false
  volumes:
  - name: data
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: ceph-claim-dynamic
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------       ----                ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled    38m                 default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/ceph-pod1 to worker1
  Warning  FailedMount  14m                 kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[data], unattached volumes=[kube-api-access-mxlkm data]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  28s (x16 over 36m)  kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[data], unattached volumes=[data kube-api-access-mxlkm]: timed out waiting for the condition
```

check below attach image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPsOK.png)

Comment: Did you ever solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about kube but you could deploy a simple kube pod and just mount a RBD there and rule out if you have a connectivity issue or a kube config issue.

Map rbd: `rbd map foopool/rbd_volume --id admin --keyring /etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring`

And see if it work.
Good luck!